# cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied when trying to run rsync command twice in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to copy the data from the `file stores` to the `google cloud bucket`.

This is the command I am using:

```
 gsutil rsync -r /fileserver/demo/dir1 gs://corp-bucket

corp-bucket: Name of my bucket
/fileserver/demo/dir1: Mount point directory (This directory contain the data of the file store)
```

This command works fine in the first time, It copies the data of the directory `/fileserver/demo/dir1` to the cloud bucket but then I delete the data from the cloud bucket and again run the same command without any changes then I get this error:

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

**NOTE: If I made even a small changes to the file of the /fileserver/demo/dir1 and run the above command then again it works fine but my question is why it is not working without any changes and is there any way to copy file without making any changes**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting the [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#limitations) #2 of rsync " The gsutil rsync command considers only the live object version in the source and destination buckets"; You can exclude /dir1... with the `-x` pattern and still let rsync makes the clean up work as the regular sync process.

Another way to copy those files will be to use [`cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#top_of_page) with `-r` option to make it recursively instead of rsync.